# Active profile. How can I accesss it?

Tags: support, profile-page

I'm sorry if this is a duplicate question, but I haven't read any answers that would help my predicament. My problem is that because of my befuddled mind I mistakenly deleted my profile. I have requested help through e-mail and received a reply but I couldn't understand what to do. My profile is still receiving rep points and appears active. I've sent several more e-mails begging for help, but I'm afraid it's fallen on deaf ears. I'm a fairly new member of Stack Exchange Home Improvement and enjoyed responding to other peoples questions. Would it be  impossible to get my old profile back? I realize it requires time that isn't always available, but I have read about similar request and  they were assisted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wait, if you deleted your profile, it shouldn't still be active. Are you sure you deleted it? Or did you just log out? We can't restore deleted profiles, but if you only logged out and the deletion wasn't carried out, you can go through [account recovery](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/account-recovery) to gain access to your account back.

If this is not helpful, feel free to email me directly - the address is in my profile - with a link to your still-active profile and a description of what happened, and I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Thank-you Anna. And also to the anonymous technician's that I troubled with any extra work. xoxoxo